# When is Istio gonna be stable (version 1.0.0)?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm interesting to use [Istio](http://istio.io) over [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io).
However, I found out that Istio still under development. (version < 1.0.0)

When is the first stable version going to be release?

Is it safe to use the current version?

Comment: Your right, its released in May. I wouldn’t recommend using it production yet.  You can use it in lower environment and test it.  Wait for some more time before using it in prod.

Comment: 1.0.0 is now released.

Answer (score 0):

See [GCP's release statement](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/05/istio-modern-approach-to-developing-and.html):

> Istio is being developed in the open on GitHub, and we invite the
>   community to join us in shaping the project as we work toward a **1.0
>   release later this year**.